# How can I fix the following error: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the file causing the problem:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import './question_model.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class DBconnect {
  final url = Uri.parse(
      'https://quizzapp-f2354-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/questions.json');
  Future<List<Question>> fetchQuestions() async {
    return http.get(url).then((response) {
      var data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<Question> newQuestions = [];
      data.forEach((key, value) {
        var newQuestion = Question(
          id: key,
          title: value['title'],
          options: Map.castFrom(value['options']),
        );
        newQuestions.add(newQuestion);
      });
      return newQuestions;
    });
  }
}
```

Here's the JSON file that I loaded into the firebase realtime database:

```json
{
    "questions": {
        "first": {
            "title": "Who is the best player in the world?",
            "options": {
                "messi": "true",
                "ronaldo": "false",
                "haaland": "false",
                "mbappe": "false"
            }
        },
        "second": {
            "title": "2 + 2 = ?",
            "options": {
                "1": "false",
                "2": "false",
                "3": "false",
                "4": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried running the app and was expecting the questions to load in the app.

Comment: Maybe you would like to log and share with us the value of `json.decode(response.body)` before you cast it to a Map.  The error is telling you you're getting a list intead.

Comment: Please format the code properly to make it readable. Also, share the stack trace coming with the exception

Comment: Please share what `print(response.body)` outputs.

Answer (score 0):

/// A problem occurred because the API was not working properly, replace your code with this and try

```
class DBconnect {
      final url = Uri.parse('https://quizzapp-f2354-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/questions.json');

  Future<List<Question>> fetchQuestions() async {
    return http.get(url).then((http.Response? response) {
      if (response?.statusCode == 200 || response?.statusCode == 201) {
        var data = json.decode(response!.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
        List<Question> newQuestions = [];
        data.forEach((key, value) {
          var newQuestion = Question(
            id: key,
            title: value['title'],
            options: Map.castFrom(value['options']),
          );
          newQuestions.add(newQuestion);
        });
        return newQuestions;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    });
  }
}
```